# Company wants to see email design portfolio, I (stupidly) never created one?

Tags: portfolio, e-mail

I screwed up bigtime.

I never considered myself to be an "email designer" until just recently, when I ended up in a couple of jobs doing just that. I've always focused on web & graphic design, and somehow ended up doing a ton of stuff with Bronto/ExactTarget/etc. However, my idiotic self never thought to SAVE any of that work for portfolio use, and now I'm interviewing for a new job where they have asked to see examples of past email work...and I don't have access to any.

What the hell do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you haven't sent any test emails to an email account you have access to? Sometimes I have sent test emails to my personal email account.

You can say that you're unable to show the email campaigns because of a contract you had with past employer and just show other design artwork that you have done.

Create 1 to 2 email campaigns for a fake email newsletter.

Comment: @A.C.: AndrewH sparked an idea. You can create a new email campaign that is your portfolio and feature some of your work within the newsletter.

Answer (score 2):

I think you really only have 2 options...

1. Tell them you don't have any projects specific to their needs to show, but.. *"here's some similar work involving HTML/CSS, responsiveness, etc. ...."*
2. Recreate something

Answer (score 0):

You didn't screw up, getting a foot in the door is the hardest part. It's good the clients asking for examples.

I agree with the comment above.  Quickly whip a couple up.  It's mostly a template workflow with graphic artists updating the graphics, colors and fonts. Sign up for a free account at MailChimp & turn this in tomorrow morning.

Stop wasting time on here and get on it!!